# How to renew game board and return back

Tags: java

I want to call the constructor in same class from a method.

I have a game board of size 10x10. For example: (2,3) has change from X to Y, then I want to see new game board with (2,3) as Y. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
public int opponentMove(int pRow, int pColumn) {

    if(ownBoard[pRow][pColumn]=='X') {
        ownBoard[pRow][pColumn] ='Y';
        System.out.println(ownBoard[pRow][pColumn]);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

but in this case I see only Y without rest of board.

Comment: You can't call constructors from methods unless you are actually initializing a new object.  However, you can call methods from constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the constructor to actually print out the entire board and now want to print the changed board. The way to do this is to create a method `printBoard()` inside your (presumable called) `Board` class (where you currently print the board in the first place).

```
class Board {

    public Board(...) {
        // initialize whatever you want
        printBoard();
    }

    private void printBoard() {
        // actually print the board
    }

    public int opponentMove(int pRow, int pColumn) {
        // before `return`ing put
        printBoard();
    }
}
```

Alternatively make `printBoard()` `public` and call it from the outside whenever you want to have the board printed.